# Filter Access table with keywords stored in another table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 3 Access tables: tblClients, tblSalesRecords, tblKeywords. They are all linked by the ClientID key. I have some of my clients who need the sales records for SPECIFIC brands only that appear in the sales description records. Hence I created the tblKeywords which hold keywords of each client (from couple of keywords to tens).

I need to VB code that I can attach to  Form/Report/Query that can fetch these records based on the keywords of each client. I was able to do it for ONE keyword only, but could not figure out how to create a full string holding all keywords.

Below is the SQL code linked to the form used to prepare the reports:

```
SELECT tblSalesRecords.SalesID, tblSalesRecords.ClientID, tblSalesRecords.ItemDescription, tblSalesRecords.Qty
FROM tblSalesRecords
WHERE (((tblSalesRecords.ItemDescription) Like "*" & [Forms].[KeywordsSubform].[Keyword] & "*"));
```

Keword table sample as below:

Client ID|Keyword
101|Samsung
101|Apple
101|Toshiba
102|Car
102|Motorbyc
102|Bus

Thank you.

Comment: Edit question to show the SQL statement as well as sample data as text tables. Are you using filter like: `WHERE somefield LIKE "*[keyword]*"` ? Using LIKE with multiple keywords would be impractical: `WHERE somefield LIKE "*[enter keyword1]*" OR somefield LIKE "*[enter keyword2]*" OR somefield LIKE "*[enter keyword3]*" OR etc`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is a having a field with the EXACT strings to match:

```
SELECT * FROM tblSalesRecords 
WHERE somefield IN (SELECT keyword FROM tblKeywords) 
AND ClientID = Forms!formname!ClientID
```

Another uses DLookup().

```
SELECT * FROM tblSalesRecords 
WHERE NOT DLookup("ClientID", "tblKeywords", "'" & [fieldname] & "' LIKE '*' & [Keyword] & '*'") IS NULL
AND ClientID = Forms!formname!ClientID;
```

Otherwise, most likely need a VBA custom function.

Comment: Thanks dear, but this will lookup for a single keyword, I need to search for all keywords per client at a time. The keywords table looks like this:

Client ID            Keyword
101                    Toshiba
101                     Samsung
101                     HP
102                      Iphone12
102                      Macbook
102                      iPad4

Any suggestion plz. Thanks.